# htaccess rule to remove parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

struggling to come up with a .htaccess rule to remove parameters from it.
Essentially I want

http://www.example.com/page/competition.html?utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=11&utm_source=11&utm_term=11.gif

to rewrite to

http://www.example.com/page/competition.html

so, anything right from the /page/compeition.html is rewritten.
Grateful for any assistance. thanks in advance

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you state that you want the long URI *rewritten* to the shorter one. Unfortunately, that isn't very clear. Assuming that you wish to simply remove the query string using a *redirect*, you can use the following:

```bsh
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=([^&]+)&utm_source=([^&]+)&utm_term=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=302,L]
```

This is a generalised condition and rule that will check for any `utm` information in the query string. If it is present, then strip out the query string.

If you wish to only do this for `page/competition.html`, then change the rule to this:

```bsh
RewriteRule ^(page/competition\.html)$ /$1? [R=302,L]
```

If you wish to simply remove any query string forming part of a request to `page/competition.html`, then you can use this instead of the above:

```bsh
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^(page/competition\.html)$ /$1? [R=302,L]
```

This basically tells Apache to check if the query string is not empty and, if it isn't, strip it out altogether.

To make the redirect permanent, change `302` to `301`.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you should be able to use the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1? [END,QSA]
```

The key in this rule is the trailing questionmark which will *not* appear in the output URL.

> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1? [END,QSA]  This rule was met, the new url is
>   http://www.example.com/page/competition.html

Try it out at the following:

http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Answer (score -1):

Do you want that only for the specific page? Or more as a general approach?

```
RewriteRule ^page/competition.html?(.+)$ /page/competition.html [L,NC]
```

That would be the very easiest form to achieve it, but would only work for the exact filename. For a more general approach, you would need to add some more placeholders.

Comment: Incorrect - `mod_rewrite` does not expose the query string to the rule. Also, your rule is backwards - the OP wants the query string to essentially be hidden, but still part of the request. I could be mistaken, but use of the word *rewrite* in the question points me in that direction.